# Unable to instantiate a generic type that uses another generic as a parameter - Cannot invoke initializer for type

Tags: swift, generics

```
class Request {

}
class Response<T: Request> {
    let request: T
    required init(request: T) {
        self.request = request
    }
}
class Adapter {        
    static func MakeRequest<T: Request, N: Response<T>>(request: T) -> N {
        let response = N(request: request)
        return response
    }
}
```

> Error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'N' with an argument list of type
>   '(request: T)'

I would like to create a response class that stores the request as a generic type.  When I try to instantiate a response passing in a generic request it returns the error above.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do does not make the most sense.

If all of your request and response objects are going to be subclasses of `Request` and `Response`, then you have no need for generics. You won't be able to define anything other than subclasses of `Request` or `Response` that will be usable in your `Adapter`. Just define everything like this:

```
class Request {
}
class Response {
    let request: Request
    required init(request: Request) {
        self.request = request
    }
}
class Adapter {
    static func MakeRequest(request: Request) -> Response {
        let response = Response(request: request)
        return response
    }
}
```

---

However, I suspect that what you really want is to define `Request` and `Response` as protocols. This will allow you to make any class or struct conform to the `Request` or `Response` protocols and thus usable in your `Adapter`. This is a great use for generics.

```
protocol Request {
}
protocol Response {
    var request: Request { get }
    init(request: Request)
}
class Adapter {
    static func MakeRequest<T: Request, N: Response>(request: T) -> N {
        let response = N(request: request)
        return response
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Based on your comment, I see that you want to use a subclass of `Request` in `Response` without having to typecast. Certainly generics could make that possible, but it will not be useful to you.

Imagine you have your `Request` and `Response` classes defined as you did:

```
class Request {
}
class Response<T: Request> {
    let request: T
    required init(request: T) {
        self.request = request
    }
}
```

And you have a special `Request` subclass defined as `MyRequest`, which contains an additional property:

```
class MyRequest: Request {
    let numberOfRetries: Int = 3
}
```

And you create a response containing a `MyRequest`:

```
let myRequest = MyRequest()
let aResponse = Response(request: myRequest)
```

This all works. But what can you do with it? In a playground, you can check `numberOfRetries` and see that it's working:

```
aResponse.request.numberOfRetries     // 3
```

But you can't write any code in a real app that will take advantage of this. Using your `Adapter` as an example, any `Adapter` instance cannot check `numberOfRetries` without being specialized, because a generic `Adapter` that accepts a generic `Response` which accepts a generic `Request` will not be able to assume that the request was a `MyRequest` instance, and thus cannot assume that `numberOfRetries` is present.

If you want your `Adapter` to be able to take advantage of a `Request` or `Response` subclass's functionality with typecasting or checking, you will need a specialized `Adapter` subclass with constraints on what `Request` and `Response` it handles. And if you are creating an `Adapter` subclass, I'd say the usefulness of generics in your situation is severely limited.

In other words, an `Adapter` instance (or any other code that deals with `Response` objects) will not be able to take advantage of a `Response` subclass's special functionality without typecasting, specifically because your use of generics means that the `Adapter` cannot assume what kind of `Response` it will be working with.

Comment: In both examples the request property stored in Response will need to be type casted into the subclass of Response every time I try to use it.  Generics would allow me to have a typed version of the subclass.

In the first example the response instantiated in the MakeRequest will be of the base Response type and not a subclass.  The init code for the subclasses would not be executed.

Setting the request property in the response as a generic type allows for any subclass of response to have the correct request type instead of just Request

Comment: I have edited my answer with more info on why generics are not going to allow what you are looking for. The TL;DR of it is that generics won't allow you to magically use a subclass's additional functionality without first checking its type. It would be good if you could provide an example of what you want to do (in code), so that we can help in a more specific way.

Answer (score 0):

Given your question and your comment on @user2194039 it is probably the best way to instantiate it directly since you need to provide the type information:

```
// if the function would work in your example you have to call it like so
let response: URLResponse<String> = Adapter.MakeRequest("Hello")

// this would be the easiest way
let response = URLResponse("Hello")
```

If your example is more complex please provide more information.